# React Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the following error:  Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Since I am using useEffect I don't see how this can result in an infinite loop. I am new to React so it could just be an obvious mistake, thanks for your time.

This is where the error occurs:
`

```
  53 |         else
  54 |         {
  55 |             setCompanies(response.data.companies); 
> 56 |             setNoCompanyFound(false);                                          
     | ^  57 |         }                                         
  58 |     }
  59 | }
```

`Here is the function:`

```
export default function FindAvailableEmployee() {
    const [noCompanyFound, setNoCompanyFound] = useState(true);
    const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);
    

    useEffect(() => { 
       getCompanies();       
      }, []) 
    
    const getCompanies = async () => {
        const response = await getMyCompanies();
        
        if(response.data.status === 200)
        {            
            if(response.data.companies.length === 0)
            {
                setNoCompanyFound(true);
            }
            else
            {
                setCompanies(response.data.companies); 
                setNoCompanyFound(false);                                          
            }                                         
        }
    }

  return (
    <div>        
        {noCompanyFound? <NoCompaniesFound/> : <FindAvailableEmployeesForm companyData={companies}/>}
    </div>      
  )
}
```

`

Comment: Probably doesn't have anything to do with it but `companyData{companies}` has a typo. (And that second state is a little redundant when you can check the length of the array in your JSX condition).

Comment: what does NoCompaniesFound do ?

Comment: @Andy the typo was not in my code, but only in the post. I will look checking array length in a JSX condition, but the code should still work the way I have it right now, right?

Comment: @Sky NoCompaniesFound returns a screen where the user can create a company

Comment: The only thing that causes this problem is you are remounting this component somehow.
Are you sure that you set an empty array as dependency of your useEffect ?
cause if you don't, it keeps calling that API and the muting the state that cause rerenders and infinite loop

Comment: @Sky looking at my network tab you are right! It is remounting. see: https://snipboard.io/Nc1AXf.jpg The dependency array of the useEffect is empty, so I am not sure what could cause this